# XSD attribute prefix namespace

Tags: xml, xsd, namespaces, attributes, xml-validation

I am trying to validate XML against XSD. I have an attribute with prefix and I can't figure out how to check this with XSD. After quite a long fight I figured out how to check an element's prefix but now I can't validate an attribute's prefix. I was trying something similar to element's prefix validation:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:p="http://www.xx.com/2014/p-Document" targetNamespace="http://www.xx.com/2014/p-Document" >

    <xs:element name="EL" type="p:EL">
    </xs:element>

     <xs:complexType name="EL">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Group">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="Table" type="p:Table" use="required"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="Table">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

And after validating such xml:

```
    <p:EL  xmlns:p="http://www.xx.com/2014/p-Document">
        <Group p:Table=""/>
    </p:EL>
```

I getting errors:

```
Cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'p:Table' Is Not Allowed To Appear In Element 'Group'.. Line '2', Column '20'.
Cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'Table' Must Appear On Element 'Group'.. Line '2', Column '20'.
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a helpful description. Show us some examples of the kind of XML you want to validate and we should be able to suggest an appropriate schema. And some examples of what should _not_ be valid might be useful too.

Comment: Sorry, now it's more detailed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Local" declarations of elements and attributes inside a `complexType` do not take on the target namespace of the schema by default. You can change this default using `elementFormDefault` and `attributeFormDefault` attributes on the `xs:schema`, but if you just want to affect one attribute rather than all of them then you can use `form` on the specific attribute declaration:

```
<xs:attribute name="Table" form="qualified" type="p:Table" use="required"/>
```

Alternatively, declare the attribute at the top level (as global top-level elements and attributes are always qualified) and `ref` it in as required.

```
 <xs:attribute name="Table" type="p:Table"/>

 <xs:complexType name="EL">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Group">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:attribute ref="p:Table" use="required"/>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```